# Simultaneous Equations (Stuck on the algebra)

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, systems-of-equations

> ***Question:*** Solve the following simultaneous equations for real values of x and y
>   $$
>  \left\{
>   \begin{array}{l}
>    9^{2x+y} - 9^x \times 3^y = 6 \\
>    \log_{x+1}(y+3) + \log_{x+1}(y+x+4) = 3
>   \end{array}
>  \right.
> $$

What I have attempted; for the first equation
$$
 9^{2x+y} - 9^x \times 3^y = 6 \\
 9^{2x+y} - 3^{2x} \times 3^y = 6 \\
 9^{2x+y} - 3^{2x+y} - 6 = 0
$$
Let $z = 3^{2x+y}$. Then
$$
 z^2 - z - 6 = 0
 \iff (z-3)(z+2) = 0
 \iff z = 3, z \ne -2
$$
where
$$
 3^{2x+y} = 3 \iff y = 1-2x.
$$
Now using the second equation I get
$$
 \log_{x+1}(y+3) + \log_{x+1}(y+x+4) = 3
$$
Substituting $y = 1-2x$
$$
 \log_{x+1}(4-2x) + \log_{x+1}(5-x) = 3.
$$
Now this is the part I am stuck on , how do I solve for $x$ algebraically?

Comment: As a typesetting note, `\times` will produce the $\times$ symbol and `\neq` will produce the $\neq$ symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You finished with $$\log_{x+1}(4-2x) + \log_{x+1}(5-x) = 3$$ Go to natural logarithms (the only ones I know !); this will then write $$\frac{\log (4-2 x)}{\log (x+1)}+\frac{\log (5-x)}{\log (x+1)}=3$$ Multiply by the denominator appearing in the lhs (hoping that $x\neq -1$) and simplify.

So, $$\log (4-2 x)+\log (5-x)=3\log(x+1)$$ that is to say $$(4-2x)\times (5-x)=(x+1)^3$$ Expand and simplify to get $$x^3+x^2+17 x-19=0$$ where $x=1$ is an obvious solution. Perform the long division to get $$x^3+x^2+17 x-19=(x-1)(x^2+2 x+19)=0$$ The quadratic term does not show real solutions (in the complex domain, they would be $(x_{1,2}=-1\pm3 i \sqrt{2})$.

So $x=1$ is your solution and you were about to get it.

## Happy New Year !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Observe
$$\log_{x+1}(y+3)+\log_{x+1}(y+x+4)=\log_{x+1}[(y+3)(y+x+4)]\text{.}$$
Now we have
$$\log_{x+1}[(y+3)(y+x+4)] = 3$$
Take both as a power of $x+1$:
$$(x+1)^{\log_{x+1}[(y+3)(y+x+4)] } = (x+1)^{3}$$
giving
$$(y+3)(y+x+4)=(x+1)^{3}\text{.}$$
[since $b^{\log_{b}(x)} = x$]

Answer (score 0):

we have $$(3^{2x+y})^2-3^{2x+y}=6$$ and $$log_{x+1}(y+3)(y+x+4)=3$$
the last equation can be written as $$(y+3)(y+x+4)=(x+1)^3$$
from the quadratic equation we get $$2x+y=1$$ can you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Writing the last  equation

$$ \log_{x+1}(4-2x) + \log_{x+1}(5-x) = 3 $$

as

$$ \log_{x+1}[(4-2x)(5-x)] = 3 $$

you can get both term as exponents of $x+1$, so that

$$ (4-2x)(5-x) = (x+1)^3 $$

This equation can be easily solved, leading to $x=1$.